# Calling action in TableView.m from customCell button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a **UIViewController** with a **tableView** in it with CustomCells, the CustomCell load a PLAY Button for some of the cells, this button are generated within the **CustomCell.m**

```
- (UIButton *)videoButton {
    if (!videoButton) {
        videoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(120, 319, 50, 30);
        [videoButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        videoButton.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:videoButton];
    }
    playIMG.hidden = false;
    return videoButton;
}

- (IBAction)PlayClicked:(id)sender {
    TableView *tvvc = [[TableView alloc] init];
    [tvvc PlayBtnClicked:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]]];
}
```

in my **TableView.m**

```
- (IBAction)PlayBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender]; //OK
    int tagNumber = [tag intValue];  //OK      
    NSString *Media = [arrayID objectAtIndex:tagNumber]; //Not Getting Result !

    NSLog(@"%@", arrayID); //Array is empty when logging it from this action
}
```

**arrayID** is **NSMutableArray**

```
arrayID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayID addObject@"123"];
[arrayID addObject@"321"];
[arrayID addObject@"231"];
```

soo i checked the array by adding an action button in my **TableView** to log the array and its not empty.

how can i fix the empty array which is actually not empty ?

Comment: Im not sure what your asking, your title seems like your asking about calling a controller method from a cell button(which you only have to change the target in `addTarget`). your present configuration creates a new controller (but does not display it) and asks the number to be logged. Make sure the `arrayID` is created and populated in the actual `init` method for the controller, so that way its created when the actual controller is, not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in much easier way than the delegate thing

removed

```
[videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the action in the custom cell .m file

```
- (IBAction)PlayClicked:(id)sender {
    TableView *tvvc = [[TableView alloc] init];
    [tvvc PlayBtnClicked:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]]];
}
```

in the **tableView.m** i added edited the action i want to link to this

```
- (IBAction)PlayBtnClicked:(UIButton*)button {
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked Tag: %d", button.tag);
}
```

and in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method i added the action to the button in the custom cell

```
if ([MediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {

        cell.videoButton.hidden = NO;
        cell.videoButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//here linking the action to the button
        cell.playIMG.hidden = NO;
}
```

now everything is working very well :)

Answer (score -1):

The array isn't your problem - you're breaking the model-view-controller nature of the table view controller and its cells. If you want a control in the cell to call a method in the table view controller, make the table view controller the delegate of the cell, and call the delegate method from the cell's button.

If the code you've posted is correct, then you're creating a new table view instance in the PlayClicked method, which is definitely not the way to do it.

As a minor stylistic point, the Cocoa convention of method naming is camelCase, with a lower-case initial letter.

Comment: can you please explain in code how to make the tableview the delegate of the cell and calling the delegate method from the cell button ? and thank you from the minor stylistic point i'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: 1. define the protocol in the table view controller class to declare the method

2. declare a delegate property on the cell class

3. when instantiating the cell, set the table view controller as the delegate e.g. `cell.delegate = self`

4. call the delegate method from the cell class in the button's action method, e.g. `[self.delegate doProtocolMethod]`

Comment: Please edit your answer with the example code, i'm still learning :)

Comment: If you need to figure out the delegation pattern, check the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

It's a key design pattern in the Cocoa frameworks, so it's important to know how it functions.